# snapshot.docChanges() not working in Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We're having issues with a listener firing at the wrong times. I tried to see the metadata changes with:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('Users').doc($scope.user.uid).collection($scope.longLanguage).doc('Missing_Word').onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
          console.log(change.doc.data());
        })
```

Here's the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: snapshot.docChanges is not a function
```

I also tried switching on metadataChanges:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('Users').doc($scope.user.uid).collection($scope.longLanguage).doc('Missing_Word').onSnapshot({includeMetadataChanges: true}, function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
      console.log(change.doc.data());
    })
```

We wrote this close to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). Any idea what we're doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 13):

[`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#onSnapshot) accepts a callback function that receives a [`DocumenSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) object.  `DocumentSnapshot` doesn't have a `docChanges` method.

It looks like you were expecting the callback to contain a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) instead, which does have `docChanges`.  You get a `QuerySnapshot` when you perform a query against a collection, not a single document as you're showing here.

Comment: The documentation shows a query against a document, not a collection. Our code is almost cut-and-paste from the documenation.

Comment: My point is that your code is querying a document, not a collection.  Document queries work differently than collection queries.  Please consult the documentation to understand the APIs in each case.

Comment: I can't get get docChanges() to work on a collection query. my code is `db.collection('users')
    .doc(uid)
    .collection('photos_selling')
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      let changes = querySnapshot.docChanges();
      console.log(changes);
    });`

Answer (score 3):

The following examples are in the docs here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots

In browser:

```js
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
    .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "modified") {
                console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "removed") {
                console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
        });
    });
```

In nodejs

```
let observer = db.collection('cities').where('state', '==', 'CA')
  .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
      if (change.type === 'added') {
        console.log('New city: ', change.doc.data());
      }
      if (change.type === 'modified') {
        console.log('Modified city: ', change.doc.data());
      }
      if (change.type === 'removed') {
        console.log('Removed city: ', change.doc.data());
      }
    });
  });
```

So please note that both `.onSnapshots` are on the `Firestore.CollectionReference`, not on `DocumentReference` (after `doc()`)

Comment: How to detect is it a new snapshot (I fired new query which has zero results - so docChanges().forEach() is not called at all) or a docChanges in old snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

If someone has this error message and is looking for an easy to understand answer:

Queries to collections return to you a **list** of documents.
In this case you loop through the list with *docChanges().forEach(change => {*

```
db.collection("cities").onSnapshot(querySnapshot => { //onSnapshot on collection
   querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
     //do whatever you want here...
   });
});
```

Queries to a document return to you a **single** document.
In this case, you do not need *docChanges()* because the snapshot of a single document does not have a function "docChanges"

```
db.collection("cities").doc("someId") //onSnapshot on a document
.onSnapshot((doc) => {
    console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something else to watch out for: this seems to depend on what version of the Firebase JS SDK you are using. Of course, please make sure to check whether you are calling `onSnapshot` on a document or a collection, as other answers have pointed out. But in regard to calling it on a collection, I was recently using 4.13.1 and `docChanges` was not a function, but when I upgraded to v.7.15 I had to change all my `snapshot.docChanges` to `snapshot.docChanges()`.

The [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-firestore_64) confirm as much as well. In v.5.0 they changed `docChanges` into a function. [See here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/firebase%404.13.1/packages/firestore/src/core/view_snapshot.ts#L162-L172) for example, from the branch with the 4.13.1 tag, where docChanges is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

**For firebase ^6.6.2:**

**docChanges() function can only run against a collection**.

Also onSnapshot may not return this function by default, but it accepts an option

```
{ includeMetadataChanges: true }
```

example:

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("/restaurant")
  .onSnapshot({ includeMetadataChanges: true }, (resp) =>
    console.log(resp.docChanges())
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see here is that you are confusing a document and a collection query. Based on your example, you are listening to changes on a specific document and hence the `snapshot.docChanges()` will throw an error because this works on a collection level. Which I guess will be a better option based on what you are trying to do, so the correct approach in your case would be;

```
firebase.firestore().collection('Users').doc($scope.user.uid).collection($scope.longLanguage).onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
    // Listen to changes here on a collection level, then add logic below to compare updated data based on the type of change that was made
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
      if (change.type === 'added') {
          console.log('New city: ', change.doc.data());
        }
        if (change.type === 'modified') {
          console.log('Modified city: ', change.doc.data());
        }
        if (change.type === 'removed') {
          console.log('Removed city: ', change.doc.data());
        }
    })
```

You can find more about this on the [firebase docs reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#node.js_3)

Answer (score -2):

This is a simple way of using `docChanges()` method:

```
        db.collection("cities").onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {

            let changes = querySnapshot.docChanges();
            for (let change of changes) {
                var data = change.doc.data();
                console.log(data);
            }


        });
```

Answer (score -3):

Remove the parenthesis from `docChanges()`, it is just `docChanges`.

Comment: Not true, it's a function. Please fix or remove your misleading answer.

Comment: If you are talking about `docChanges` called on a collection snapshot, then make sure to check what version of Firebase js sdk you are using. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62208723/6952495) for more on this.